# Drawer overlapping button QML

Tags: qt, qml

In the example below the Button component doesn't work because Drawer dragMargin overlap it.

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Drawer example")

Drawer {
        id: menu
        dragMargin: 60
        width: window.width * 0.85
        height: window.height
        background: Rectangle {
            color: "blue"
        }
    }
    Button {
        id: log
        text: "Click me!"
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.left: parent.left
        onClicked: {
            console.log("Clicked!");
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to fix this issue? I tried to change z properties but it doesn't work.

Comment: What are you going to do here? In `ApplicationWindow` a `Drawer` (as all popups) is displayed above other items in the scene so everything works as it should.

Comment: I am looking for a solution for this as well. I am trying to put a button on top of the `Drawer`, but the Drawer's `dragMargin` masks the button. If I set the `dragMargin` to `0`, then the button is clickable. I understand that the `Drawer` is a `Popup`. However, when the Drawer is not opened, why is it masking controls in the window? Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

I found this [link](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-59141) on the Qt forum. It seems that the problem described is an open issue to be resolved by Qt.